# How can a bot send private messages from the context of a Task Module submit?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a use case where the bot will need to send private messages to users in a Teams team after another user has submitted through a task module. The message is basically, "Joe Schmo has shared something with you."

I've tried using this code sample here and this what I'll be referencing: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teamsConversationBot.js#L172

However, it appears to only work when the context is a message to the bot, whether private or in a channel.

When this code is called from a `task/submit` event the `context` object is modified in such a way that it throws an error:
`(node:14206) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked`

The line that this error occurs at is simply:
`const ref = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);`

While debugging I noticed that at the start of the `messageAllMembersAsync` function the `context` object has an `activity`, but after executing `TeamsInfo.getPagedMembers()` that the `activity` is `null`.

What do I need to do for `messageAllMembersAsync` to work in the context of submitting a Task Module?

Comment: Hi @ross_troha, 

Sorry for the delayed response.

We are working on it practically and checking with our Internal Team will update you soon.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT So this isn't possible?

Comment: Hi @ross_troha, could you please confirm whether are you getting members details in TeamsInfo.getPagedMembers().

Comment: Hi @ross_troha, could you please confirm, that are you adding bot to teams channel?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you should use [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet).

1. Save the [required information about user 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#get-the-user-id-team-id-or-channel-id)
2. When user 2 completes the task you can send a message to user 1 by using [Proactive Message sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#samples).

Check how `/api/notify` is used to send proactive message: [teams-conversation-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/index.js#L72)

Please let us know if you are facing any issues.